# Find Recent Frequent Flyers in SQL Database

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to find a list of frequent flyers in a database.

There are 2 important tables: Demographics and Visits.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT Demographics.[First Name], Demographics.[Last Name], Demographics.ID
FROM Demographics INNER JOIN Visits ON (Demographics.ID=Visits.ID)
WHERE Visits.[Visit Date] > #1/1/2019#
GROUP BY Demographics.[First Name], Demographics.[Last Name], Demographics.ID
HAVING COUNT(Visits.ID) >=5;
```

It runs and returns people who visited last year 5 or more times. However, what I ACTUALLY want is people who visited 5 or more times, and have at least 1 visit last year. I assume the answer involves an ORDER BY clause and removing the WHERE clause, but I'm not sure how to phrase it.

I am using Microsoft Access on Windows 7 (I know...) if that helps.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about it for a while, I was able to answer my own question, I believe.

Here is my solution:

```
SELECT Demographics.[First Name], Demographics.[Last Name], Demographics.ID
FROM Demographics INNER JOIN Visits ON (Demographics.ID=Visits.ID)
WHERE Demographics.ID IN 
(
SELECT Demographics.[First Name], Demographics.[Last Name], Demographics.ID
FROM Demographics INNER JOIN Visits ON (Demographics.ID=Visits.ID)
WHERE Visits.[Visit Date] > #1/1/2019#
GROUP BY Demographics.[First Name], Demographics.[Last Name], Demographics.ID #parts of this line are superfluous
)
GROUP BY Demographics.[First Name], Demographics.[Last Name], Demographics.ID
HAVING COUNT(Visits.ID) >=5;
```

The subquery checks for a visit in the past year, and the outer query checks for total number of visits.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the simpler solution:

```
SELECT d.[First Name], d.[Last Name], d.ID
FROM Demographics as d INNER JOIN
     Visits as v
     ON d.ID = v.ID
GROUP BY d.[First Name], d.[Last Name], d.ID
HAVING COUNT(Visits.ID) >= 5 AND
       MAX(v.[Visit Date]) > #1/1/2019#;
```

I added the table aliases so the query is easier to write and read.  What makes it simpler is moving the logic from the `WHERE` to the `HAVING`.